# I want to return the result when all the queries in the loop is done(express.js, react.js, mysql)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working on a side project using react and express.

I want to send the drop data of 7 days of a specific item in my database in the list for search.

So I wrote the code like this.

Use `date(droped_at) = date(date_add(now(),interval -*${i}* DAY)` and for loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    var resultSql1 = `SELECT T.channel_name, T.channel_number, T.VALUE, T.num from(SELECT itemId, channel_name, channel_number, COUNT(*) AS VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value DESC) NUM FROM item_drop_exception WHERE  itemId = (SELECT itemId FROM item_exception WHERE itemid = '${id}') AND date(droped_at) = date(date_add(now(),interval -${i} DAY)) GROUP BY channel_name, channel_number) T WHERE T.NUM<=3 ORDER BY T.num ORDER BY T.NUM`
    db.query(resultSql1, id, (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
            list1.push(data);
            if (list1.length == 7) {
                res.send(list1);
            }
        }
        else {
            res.send(err);
        }
    })
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I know the method is wrong.

I think the next loop is going on before the query results come in, but I don't know what to do.

Is it right to bring in seven days of data like that?

I want to send the data to the front when all results are the append and complete.

It's not easy because I'm self-taught, I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has a small error.

You have a double `ORDER BY t.NUM` at the end, so when you remove it the query runs. But if it gets you the right result, is only answerable , fi we had data

So

```
var resultSql1 = `SELECT T.channel_name, T.channel_number, T.VALUE, T.num from(SELECT itemId, channel_name, channel_number, COUNT(*) AS VALUE, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by value DESC) NUM FROM item_drop_exception WHERE  itemId = (SELECT itemId FROM item_exception WHERE itemid = '${id}') AND date(droped_at) = date(date_add(now(),interval -${i} DAY)) GROUP BY channel_name, channel_number) T WHERE T.NUM<=3 ORDER BY T.num`
```

Would give you a result for every days

Comment: Wow... I really didn't think of that. Thank you. I've modified it, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Turn your function call into a promise, then `await` it inside each loop, ensuring each db query runs one by one.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const dbQueryAsync = promisify(db.query);

async function getData(req, res) {
    var { id } = req.params;
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        var resultSql1 = `SELECT ... `;
        try {
            var data = await dbQueryAsync(resultSql1, id);
            list.push(data);
        } catch(err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
    }
    res.send(list);
);
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I know how to use and example **promise** now!! The code above works well after fix the query, but I think it's the wrong way to implement it, so I'll try to correct it in the way you told me!